# Identify bad data in People soft table PS_Job

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am quite new to SQL. 
I need to get all the record from PS_Job table based on highlighted condition.

Background:

On 6th January, a new row is keyed moving this person from being a temp(CWR) to perm(EMP).The new row is a new employee RCD- 1. This is correct.

However, they should not key a row against a new RCD without inactivating the old one first.
So, at this point in time, this person has two active rows. This is wrong.

I need to find out all such records in PS_Job table.

```
Date           EmpID   EmpRCD  HR_Status   Status
24/Sep/12   2801    0          A              CWR
01/Jan/14   2801    0          A              CWR
**06/Jan/14 2801    1          A              EMP
01/Jun/14   2801    0          I              CWR**
01/Apr/15   2801    1          A              EMP
17/Apr/15   2801    1          A              EMP
01/May/15   2801    1          A              EMP
```

Help Please

Comment: am I mistaking something here or does this person have 6 active rows?